# Chartjs time serie in wrong format

Tags: chart.js

I am using Chartjs to display time series, but when I pass this data as input nothing it's displayed.

[image]

Data

```
let serie = [{"x": 1594887960*1000, "y": 95.95},{"x": 1596488640*1000,"y": 42.95}]
      

this.chartJS.data.datasets[0].data = serie
this.chartJS.update()
```

if instead I use this, it works.

```
serie = [{"x": '2020-01-01', "y": 95.95},{"x": '2020-01-31',"y": 42.95}]
```

[image]

but I'd like to timestamp for performance, easy sorting, and better labels ( DAY MONTH format).

Chart JS options

```
this.chartJS = new Chart(this.$refs.chart, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [],
                fill: false,
                borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                stepped: false,
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        title:      {
            display: true,
            text:    "Chart.js Time Scale"
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type:       "time",
                time:       {
                    tooltipFormat: 'll',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day'
                    }
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display:     true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

EDIT:

Solved using

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import { format } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(data[0]*1000), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine with the initial data you provided. I only corrected the [`xAxes.time`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/time.html) definition but even without this change, it works.

> Maybe you're using an outdated version of Chart.js v2 or you don't use the bundled version of Chart.js that includes Moment.js (required for the time axis) in a single file.

Please take a look at your runnable code below:

```js
const chartJS = new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      stepped: false,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js Time Scale"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
          tooltipFormat: 'll'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

let serie = [{"x": 1594887960*1000, "y": 95.95},{"x": 1596488640*1000,"y": 42.95}];      
chartJS.data.datasets[0].data = serie;
chartJS.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I did work using this:
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import { format } from 'date-fns'
format(new Date(data[0]*1000), 'yyyy-MM-dd')